# Xamarin iOS, Adding WKWebView in code behind, nothing happen after deploy

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, wkwebview

I am trying to add the WKWebView component in code behind. After built and deployed and run in the iPhone simulator, there is only a white blank page, nothing else. What have I done wrong. below is my code:

```
using System;
using WebKit;
using UIKit;
using Foundation;

namespace bbbb
{
    public partial class ViewController : UIViewController
    {
        WKWebView wk = null;

        protected ViewController(IntPtr handle) : base(handle)
        {
            // Note: this .ctor should not contain any initialization logic.
        }

        public override void LoadView()
        {
            base.LoadView();
            NSCoder nc = new NSCoder();
            wk = new WKWebView(nc);
            View.Add(wk);
        }

        public override void ViewDidLoad()
        {
            base.ViewDidLoad();
            // Perform any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
            string url = "https://www.apple.com";
            NSUrl nSUrl = new NSUrl(url);
            NSUrlRequest urlRequest = new NSUrlRequest(nSUrl);
            wk.LoadRequest(urlRequest);
        }

        public override void DidReceiveMemoryWarning()
        {
            base.DidReceiveMemoryWarning();
            // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `NCCoder` constructor is for archiving/serializations (i.e. Storyboard/xib instancing).

Use the constructor that accepts a frame (`CGRect`)  and `WKWebViewConfiguration`.

#### Example:

```
var webView = new WKWebView(View.Frame, new WKWebViewConfiguration());
Add(webView);
using (var url = NSUrl.FromString("https://xamarin.com"))
using (var request = NSUrlRequest.FromUrl(url))
{
    webView.LoadRequest(request);
}
```